# Reboot the RDS Aurora (MySQL) Automatically

Tags: amazon-web-services

Is it possible to reboot the RDS (Aurora MySQL) automatically using CRON Job or is there any other way around?

Comment: I also noticed that almost all your questions have answers, yet not a single one accepted. Accepting good answers is not only a good practice, but it reduces number of duplicates and increases chances for your questions to be actually answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can setup [EventBridge scheduled rule](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/eb-create-rule-schedule.html) to trigger a lambda function, which in turn is going to use [reboot_db_cluster](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/rds.html#RDS.Client.reboot_db_cluster).

Comment: Thank you Marcin. Appreciate your response. Will going to check it.

Comment: Would it be possible to just reboot just the writer instance and not the cluster? I have an Aurora Multi-AZ DB cluster.

Comment: @Bimbs There is `reboot_db_instance`, so you can try that.

Comment: Hi @Marcin, Thank you. Reboot is working now.

Comment: @Bimbs No problem. Glad it worked out:-)